# Validate phone number length from starting digits in WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, checkout

I would like to add custom validation to WooCommerce checkout page phone number:

- If the phone number starts with "02" the length should be 9 digits max
- If the phone number starts with "08" the length should be 10 digits max

Here is the code what I have so far:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'njengah_custom_checkout_field_process');

function njengah_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    global $woocommerce;

      // Check if set, if its not set add an error. This one is only requite for companies
    if ( ! (preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}$/D', $_POST['billing_phone'] ))){
        wc_add_notice( "Incorrect Phone Number! Please enter valid 10 digits phone number"  ,'error' );
    }
}
```

Comment: _"start 02 maximun 9 numbers"_ - so `02` on its own would be a valid number then ...? That doesn't seem to make much sense. Basically, your requirements as currently given, could be expressed by `^(02[0-9]{0,7}|08[0-9]{0,8})$` - but they really don't seem to make that much sense in the first place. Also, what about phone numbers starting with anything else but 02 or 08? Are those to be considered _invalid_? Or simply not have any restrictions applied at all?

Answer (score 2):

With the following code, an error message will be thrown avoiding checkout if the inputted phone number:

- starts with "02" and if the string length has not 9 digits,
- starts with "08" and if the string length has not 10 digits,
- does not start with "02" or "08",
- is not totally numerical.

The code:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_checkout_billing_phone_validation');
function custom_checkout_billing_phone_validation() {
    if ( isset($_POST['billing_phone']) && ! empty($_POST['billing_phone']) ) {
        $phone  = str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['billing_phone']);
        $length = strlen($phone);

        // Number starting with "02" with more digits than 9
        if ( strpos($phone,'02') === 0 && is_numeric($phone) && $length == 9 ) {
            wc_add_notice( __('Incorrect Phone Number! Please enter valid 9 digits phone number', 'woocommerce'), 'error' );
        } 
        // Number starting with "08" with more digits than 10
        elseif ( strpos($phone,'08') === 0 && is_numeric($phone) && $length == 10 ) {
            wc_add_notice( __('Incorrect Phone Number! Please enter valid 10 digits phone number', 'woocommerce'), 'error' );
        } 
        // Optional: Number not starting with "02" or "08"
        elseif ( ! ( strpos($phone,'02') === 0 || strpos($phone,'08') === 0 ) ) {
            wc_add_notice( __('Incorrect Phone Number! Phone number must start with "02" or "08"', 'woocommerce'), 'error' );
        }
        // Optional: Not numerical input
        elseif ( ! is_numeric($phone)  ) {
            wc_add_notice( __('Incorrect Phone Number! Phone number only accept numbers', 'woocommerce'), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.